# Solution of ODE with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please help me solve the following ODE $$ \left( D^4 +  D ^2 + 1 \right) y  = e^{-x/2} \cos \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x \right) $$ where $D = \frac{d}{dx}$?

---

What I've tried?

Here aux equation $(D^4 +  D ^2 + 1)y = 0$

upon substitution of $D^2$ as m above eqn can be written as $m^2 +  m + 1 = 0$ which would have complex roots as $ \alpha_{1} = \frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3} } {2}$ & $\alpha_{2} = \frac{-1 - i\sqrt{3} } {2}$ but these are not roots we are looking for. These are possible values of $D^2$ upon substituting the same in above roots will give us required 4 roots as $\sqrt{\alpha_{1}} $, $- \sqrt{\alpha_{1}} $, $\sqrt{\alpha_{2}} $, $- \sqrt{\alpha_{2}} $ but these are not really nice to write complimentary soln. Can someone help me how to better represent complementary solution in this case

Comment: Hi, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried solving aux equation but it turns ugly as roots are not real and complex numbers also come in form of square root. I think particular integral can be calculated little easily with changing right hand side in form of real part of e^

Comment: Would you edit the question and include all the details of your work? Like , what are steps you did before it turned ugly? What’s the auxiliary eqn? What’s the integral you think you should calculate? This will help gain positive attention for your question.

Comment: @insipidintegrator added the details

Comment: You use the outer completion $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ to get simple forms for the roots. You will get resonance in two of these roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an answer based on @Lutz Lehmann's comment, all credits to him.

---

As mentioned in the question, the auxiliary equation is:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&         0 = m^4 + m^2 + 1\\
&\implies& 0 = m^4 + 2m^2 + 1 - m^2\\
&\implies& 0 = \left(m^2 + 1\right)^2 - m^2\\
&\implies& 0 = \left(m^2 + 1 + m\right)\left(m^2 + 1 - m\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Hence, the roots will be:

\begin{eqnarray}
m_1 &=& \frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
m_2 &=& \frac{-1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
m_3 &=& \frac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
m_4 &=& \frac{1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

which are good enough to write the complementary soln as:

\begin{eqnarray}
y_c &=& {a_1 e^{\left(-1 + i\sqrt{3}\right)x/2} + a_2 e^{\left(-1 - i\sqrt{3}\right)x/2} + a_3 e^{\left(1 + i\sqrt{3}\right)x/2} + a_4 e^{\left(1 - i\sqrt{3}\right)x/2}}\\
y_c &=& {e^{-x/2}\left(a_1e^{i\sqrt{3}x/2} + a_2e^{-i\sqrt{3}x/2}\right) + e^{x/2}\left(a_3 e^{i\sqrt{3}x/2} + a_4 e^{- i\sqrt{3}x/2}\right)}
\end{eqnarray}

Upon using:
$$
e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x \quad\text{and}\quad e^{-ix} = \cos x - i \sin x$$
we get:
$$y_c = {e^{-x/2}\left(c_1 \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}\right) + c_2 \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}\right)\right) + e^{x/2}\left(c_3 \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}\right) + c_4 \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}\right)\right)}$$

The particular integral can be calculated by:

$$y_p = \Re\left(\frac{1}{D^4 + D^2 + 1}\left(e^{-x/2}e^{i\sqrt 3x/2}\right)\right)$$

and finally:

$$y = y_c + y_p$$

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the auxiliary equation is D^4+ D^2+ 1= 0.  Letting x= D^2, x^2+ x+ 1= 0.
x= (-1+/- sqrt(1- 4))/2= -1/2+/- i sqrt(3).  So D= +/- sqrt(-1+/- i sqrt(3)).  The two "+/-" give 4 distinct complex roots.  Since the coefficients of the original equation are real, there are two complex conjugate pairs.

Write the two x values in polar form to find D, the square root- if x has absolute value r and argument theta, then D, the square root of x, has absolute value sqrt(r) and argument theta/2.